# Refer to RadioButton_Checkedchanged value from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I'm writing a little program that should handle conversion between CSV and XML and from XML to TXT. In the main form I've inserted two radio buttons that the user will click to start the desired conversion.

So far I have to .cs files: MainForm.cs and ConversionForm.cs.

In MainForm.cs I have declared MainForm as static to give ConversionForm access to its methods.

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static MainForm mform = null;
```

... Then I inserted the functions for the event handler that checks the change:

```
    public void CSVConversionRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CSVConversionRadio.Checked = true;
    }

    public void TXTConversionRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.TXTConversionRadio.Checked = true;
    }
```

...

In ConversionForm I have a "Convert" button that should handle the conversion based on the user's input choice.

```
    public void conversionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (MainForm.mform.CSVConversionRadio.Checked = true)
        {
            CSVConversion();
        }

        if (MainForm.mform.TXTConversionRadio.Checked = true)
        {
            TXTConversion();
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm facing is that when the function checks the state of the radio buttons, the program returns "null", throwing an exception. Before doing some changes to the code, that is, declaring the static function

`public static MainForm mform = null;`

MainForm.mform.CSVConversionRadio.Checked was always returning a status of "false", probably because a new form (Conversion) was being instantiated and the event handler reset their state to the default.

So, here are my questions:

1. How can I pass the current value of the radio buttons to the Conversion Form, allowing the conversion functions to execute according to the user's choice?
2. Generally, how can i reference properties, methods and fields from another form, without creating a new instance, but only pointing to the previous one still opened?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I don't think you need to set the checkbox value again in the CheckChanged event. Try commenting that line out and see what happens.

Comment: Also, you don't mean `if (MainForm.mform.CSVConversionRadio.Checked = true)`. You mean `if (MainForm.mform.CSVConversionRadio.Checked == true)`, which is the same as `if (MainForm.mform.CSVConversionRadio.Checked)`

Comment: Actually, I now changed to if (MainForm.mform.CSVConversionRadio.Checked) but nothing changes.Null Reference Exception is being thrown.

Comment: You have a logic problem here and probably some misunderstanding of OOP. If mform is null and never point to a valid instance of MainForm how could you try to call methods out of a null reference?

Comment: You are right. I defined mform as null basing on this article:http://www.techrepublic.com/article/opening-form-instances-in-c/1050650. Before that, as i wrote, I had no exceptions but the conversion functions weren't triggered as the state of radio buttons was always returning "false"

Comment: That article is from 2002! Please be careful with the Internet. It will be showing that 2002 article in 2022!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of sharing information between forms.

I think an easy way for you is to have a mediator class that both forms are aware of.

```
public class ConversionContext : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private ConversionType type;

    public ConversionType Type {
        get { return type; }
        set {
            if (type != value) {
                type = value;
                onPropertyChanged("ConversionType");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void onPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public enum ConversionType { None, Xls, Csv, Txt }
```

Then, when you're creating your forms, you pass an instance of the same ConversionContext to them, using either a constructor or properties on both forms. If you're using a property, this is how it can be done.

```
private ConversionContext context;
public ConversionContext SharedContext {
   get { return context; }
   set {
       if (context == value) {
          return;
       }
       if (context != null) {
           context.PropertyChanged -= onContextPropertyChanged;
       }
       context = value;
       context.PropertyChanged += onContextPropertyChanged;
   }
}
```

In your main form you can add an event handler for when the user checks a control that sets this type.

```
public void CSVConversionRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    context.Type = ConversionType.Csv;
}
```

When setting the type, the PropertyChanged event is triggered, that you can pick up on and respond to in your forms.

```
private void onContextPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
     switch (context.Type) {
         case ConversionType.Xls :
              // check a checkbox that represents xls
         break;
         // handle the other file types
     }
}
```

And when pressing the button in your ConversionForm, the type is set

```
public void conversionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    switch (context.Type) {
        case ConversionType.Csv:
            CSVConversion();
            break;
        case ConversionType.Txt:
            TXTConversion();
            break;
    }
}
```

This also reduces the dependencies between the forms, leading to [looser coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) between the two.

Comment: Patrick, thank you. Also, Steve, thanks for your solution. Patrick, honestly i think that your solution is far too complex for me to deploy. I tried but I'm getting a exceptions over exceptions. I would need a simple one, as the one from Steve, that also is giving me errors.

Comment: What exceptions are you experiencing?

Comment: Steve, on your solution i get an error using this. here ConversionForm conv = new ConversionForm(this); and i get 2 errors here. return (this.TXTConversionRadio.Checked); vstudio expexts a set or get accessors...I think i'm going to create two distingued forms for the covnersion...

Comment: @user1776401, please post your comment on my answer, otherwise I will not be notified by SO system. Could you tell me the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Throw away that static variable mform. Is of no use if you leave at null value.
Instead when you call the constructor of ConversionForm from MainForm pass the instance of MainForm to the instance of ConversionForm

```
ConversionForm conv = new ConversionForm(this);
```

then in the constructor of ConversionForm save the instance passed in a global variable

```
public partical class ConversionForm:Form
{
    MainForm _currentInstanceMainForm = null
    public ConversionFomr(MainForm f)
    {
        _currentInstanceMainForm = f;
    }
}
```

now when you need to call public methods of MainForm you could use the instance passed at contruction time

```
public void conversionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_currentInstanceMainForm.CSVConversionRadio.Checked == true)
    {
        CSVConversion();
    }

    if (currentInstanceMainForm.TXTConversionRadio.Checked == true)
    {
        TXTConversion();
    }
}
```

However It is better to isolate the internal controls of MainForm and never let an external form access directly the controls of MainForm.
To allow this pattern you need to prepare two public properties that every external form could check to get information on the state of MainForm controls

in MainForm add these two public properties

```
 public bool CSVConversionRequired
 {
     get { return (this.CSVConversionRadio.Checked); }
 }

 public bool TXTConversionRequired
 {
     get { return (this.TXTConversionRadio.Checked); }
 }
```

and change the ConversionForm to

```
public void conversionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_currentInstanceMainForm.CSVConversionRequired == true)
        CSVConversion();

    if (currentInstanceMainForm.TXTConversionRequired == true)
    {
        TXTConversion();
    }
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty of adding get accessors to the properties.

Comment: oops, that's really a signal. It's time to hit the sack. Thanks Patrick.

Comment: Thanks Steve. However, after some trial, I couldn't solve this. Coding exactly as you suggested gives me some null exceptions on some elements. For examplet ,here,     if (_currentInstanceMainForm.CSVConversionRequired == true)
        CSVConversion();
the compiler returns me a null exception, probably because of this:MainForm _currentInstanceMainForm = null.

Comment: Yes it is initially null, it is supposed that your ConversionForm is created by the MainForm instance and in that point you pass the this reference to the just created instance of ConversionForm. Then you use the internal variable (at least until the MainForm is closed)